# cp: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.jni.dylib: Operation not permitted

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, openni

I am currently trying to install OpenNi and SensorKinect drivers on my mac OS X el capitan.
I downloaded OpenNI and SensorKinect drivers and used sudo ./install.sh 
and i got this:

```
copying shared libraries...cp: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.dylib: Operation not permitted
cp: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.jni.dylib: Operation not permitted
cp: /usr/lib/libnimCodecs.dylib: Operation not permitted
cp: /usr/lib/libnimMockNodes.dylib: Operation not permitted
cp: /usr/lib/libnimRecorder.dylib: Operation not permitted
```

I can't really find what the problem might be and I have already checked similar posts here.

Comment: You should install into `/usr/local/lib`, not `/usr/lib` and you'll need to elevate privileges by running that script via `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

It is a security feature of Apple's macOS operating system introduced in OS X El Capitan.[System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection).That means you can not copy file to some system folders even if by sudo command.

Still you can [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11), but not recommend.

The best way is to change your install.sh to copy lib files to /usr/local/lib
from

```
74 INSTALL_LIB=$rootfs/usr/lib
75 INSTALL_BIN=$rootfs/usr/bin
76 INSTALL_INC=$rootfs/usr/include/ni
77 INSTALL_VAR=$rootfs/var/lib/ni
78 INSTALL_JAR=$rootfs/usr/share/java
```

to

```
74 INSTALL_LIB=$rootfs/usr/local/lib
75 INSTALL_BIN=$rootfs/usr/local/bin
76 INSTALL_INC=$rootfs/usr/local/include/ni
77 INSTALL_VAR=$rootfs/var/lib/ni
78 INSTALL_JAR=$rootfs/usr/local/share/java
```

and I made it.